# Injecting code into generated xText classes

Tags: xtext

A rule in xText called "Component" will typically generate a class "Component" in the src-gen folder.
I would like to add additional methods to these classes without them being overridden every time I make minor changes to the DSL. What's the proper way to inject my own code into these classes and is there a way to make all classes extend my own root class instead of the default EObject?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have two choices:

- You can use a `IXtext2EcorePostProcessor` to modify the EMF-model which Xtext inferred from your grammar. The actual code generation is done by EMF, so you have to fiddle your code through that bottleneck. The details are described in a [blog of Christian Dietrich](http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/customizing-xtext-metamodel-inference-using-xtend2/). This approach is only suitable for small modifications.
- You can use the "generation gap pattern" (a.k. "implementation gap pattern") which allows you the write classes which derive from the generated model classes. Here you can add anything you want. The details are described in a [blog of Heiko Behrens](http://heikobehrens.net/2009/04/23/generation-gap-pattern/). This approach is better suited for large scale modifcations by inheritance.

You may of course mix the two approaches...

Comment: Looks like it will take some time to implement but on first glance this looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks so much :-)

Comment: I was trying to go with the second approach but quickly noticed that he is using the xtend2 Generator class whereas xtext has its own generator class with hard-coded outlets. Is this approach adaptable to the xtext Generator? If not, how can I keep the GeneratorFragments with the xtend2 Generator?